# Importing maya models into unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, maya

I made a stone tomahawk in Maya 2015 and imported it into Unity 5 as a .mb. I imported the textures separately and linked them up with the materials in Unity. The problem is that the texture for the wood grip and the axe head are displaying as plain grey and brown. The texture for the rope that is tied around the stone looks great.

Could someone instruct me in what I'm doing wrong?

If you need more information just let me know.

**Tomahawk in Maya**
[image]

**Tomahawk in Unity**
[image]

Comment: The textures have been included in your assets? They have been assigned to the appropriate slots within the materials?

Comment: In Unity, beside your imported .mb file, there should be a Materials folder. Select a material, and in the Inspector's Shader area, assign a texture to the Albedo property.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using Diffuse Shader with your Material. If So? Try Unlit/Texture Shader
 and Assign your texture to the Material you are using. I hope it would solve your problem.